# How can I add the up the result from a For loop - Java

Tags: java

Here's the code I wrote so far, I want to add the total that each mouse and rat solved, but it's showing an incorrect amount.

How many mazes did mouse 1 solve? 4

How many mazes did mouse 2 solve? 0

How many mazes did mouse 3 solve? 1

How many mazes did mouse 4 solve? 4

How many mazes did rat 1 solve? 2

How many mazes did rat 2 solve? 3

How many mazes did rat 3 solve? 0

How many mazes did rat 4 solve? 4

The mouse solved 8 . And the rats solved 8

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ratloop {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        mazeRun();
        System.exit(0);
                                    }
        public static void mazeRun()
        {
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            int mouseTest;
            int mouseSolved = 1;
            for (mouseTest= 1; mouseTest <=4; mouseTest++)
                {
                    mouseSolved = randomGenerator.nextInt(5);
                    System.out.println("How many mazes did mouse " + mouseTest + " solve? " + mouseSolved);
                    mouseSolved = mouseSolved + mouseTest;
                }

                int ratTest;
                int ratSolved = 1;
                for (ratTest= 1; ratTest <=4; ratTest++)
                {
                    ratSolved = randomGenerator.nextInt(5);
                    System.out.println("How many mazes did rat " + ratTest + " solve? " + ratSolved);
                    ratSolved = ratSolved + ratTest;    
                }

                System.out.println("The mouse solved " + mouseSolved + " . And the rats solved " + ratSolved);

        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding numbers within a loop, don't mix the loop index with the numbers you're manipulating.

```
int mouseSolvedTotal = 0;
for (int mouseTest = 1; mouseTest <= 4; mouseTest++) {
  int mouseSolved = randomGenerator.nextInt(5);
  System.out.println("How many mazes did mouse " + mouseTest + " solve? " + mouseSolved);
  mouseSolvedTotal += mouseSolved;
}

int ratSolvedTotal = 0;
for (int ratTest= 1; ratTest <= 4; ratTest++) {
  int ratSolved = randomGenerator.nextInt(5);
  System.out.println("How many mazes did rat " + ratTest + " solve? " + ratSolved);
  ratSolvedTotal += ratSolved;    
}
```

Comment: I understand what I did wrong now. The program is showing the correct total. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
mouseSolved = randomGenerator.nextInt(5);
```

is resetting your count to a random number each time through the loop. You'll want to use a different variable for that.

Part of what's causing your trouble is you're using `mouseSolved` for two different things. You're using it to store the total number of mazes solved and you're using it to store the number of mazes solved on each iteration of the loop. It can't do both of those. You need two variables, like `mouseSolvedTotal` and `mouseSolvedCurrent` to handle those two ideas.

Comment: I've tried adding a different variable, but it's still the same

`mouseSolved = randomGenerator.nextInt(5);
      System.out.println("How many mazes did mouse " + mouseTest + " solve? " + mouseSolved);
mouseTotalmaze = mouseSolved;
mouseTotalmaze = mouseSolved + mouseSolved;`

Comment: `mouseTotalmaze = mouseSolved + mouseSolved;` This is adding the solved value twice, which is no good.